# Removing Data points having difference less than 2 degrees

Tags: r

I have a tibble and one of the columns is temperature values like given.

`65.12, 64.94, 64.76, 64.58, 64.40, 64.58, 64.76, 64.94, 64.76, 67.28, 64.76, 64.40 .......` etc upto 8,000 values.

Considering the 1st data(65.12) as the present reference value, I want to remove the successive values which have absolute difference of less than 0.5.

Once the 2nd data point is obtained, it has to be the new reference point (64.58) as shown below.

So the output should be like this:

```
65.12, 64.58,  67.28, 64.76, .....
```

Any Ideas or Suggestions will be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit dirty but working:

```
values=c(65.12, 64.94, 64.76, 64.58, 64.40, 64.58, 64.76, 64.94, 64.76, 67.28, 64.76, 64.40)
# Current reference value
ref=values[1]
# Values to keep at then end (for now only the first)
to_keep=c(1)
# Threshold for the difference
threshold=0.5
for (i in 2:length(values))
{
  if(abs(values[i]-ref)>threshold)
  {
    to_keep=c(to_keep,i)
    ref=values[i]
  }
}
output=values[to_keep]
```

Tell me if you need more explanation on how it work

Comment: Thanks.Is there any way to do it without a for loop, like using some packages of R. I don't want to the data processing part to be slow as there is  huge amount of data.

Comment: It is a quite particular problem, so I don't know how to do it without a loop. Since it is really an iterative process, i.e. you need to look at elements one-by-ones, I am not sure that a package can make it really more efficient. But if you have 8000 points only, it will be really fast

Comment: @Chelmy88 I thought loop would be slow but doesn't seem so. +1

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way with `?Reduce` -

```
v <- c(65.12, 64.94, 64.76, 64.58, 64.40, 64.58, 64.76, 64.94, 64.76, 67.28, 64.76, 64.40)

Reduce(function(x, y) {
  if(abs(x[length(x)] - y) > 0.5) c(x, y) else x
}, v)

# [1] 65.12 64.58 67.28 64.76
```

**Benchmarks -**

Surprisingly, the loop is actually ever so slightly faster for vector of length 8000. If the loop looks messy then just package it in a function (say `keep`).

```
set.seed(2)
v <- runif(8000, 60, 70)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  shree = Reduce(function(x, y) {
          if(abs(x[length(x)] - y) > 0.5) c(x, y) else x
         }, as.list(v)),
  chelmy88 = keep(v, 0.5)
)

# check results
all(abs(diff(shree)) > 0.5) # [1] TRUE
all(abs(diff(chelmy88)) > 0.5) # [1] TRUE    
identical(shree, chelmy88) # [1] TRUE

Unit: milliseconds
     expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
    shree 88.0752 93.91605 100.09783 95.58430 99.09155 311.6982   100
 chelmy88 83.4297 85.41145  98.44263 87.62025 90.54640 353.2479   100
```

Comment: Here you take the difference only from the previous entry, not from the previous reference point as requested I think

Comment: i think (abs(tails(x,1) - y) > 0.5) is right instead of '<'. Will check it once.

Comment: @Shree Can you help me with an update. Since the values are a column in a dataframe, when i do the above function to single column using "mutate" function, the values are deleted, but I am getting an error as the other columns of dataframe are still present and the dimensions of all columns does not match. Is there a way to do it to delete the complete rows when the value of temperature is also removed?