# Replacing unwanted values with NA/NULL

Tags: r

I have a long list of a vector, and the unwaqnted values have to be replaced with NA/NULL as described.

`65.12, 64.94, 64.76, 64.58, 64.40, 64.58, 64.76, 64.94, 64.76, 67.28, 64.76, 64.40 .......` is the vector/array I have upto 8000 values.

Considering the 1st data(65.12) as the present reference value, I want to replace  the successive values which have absolute difference of less than 0.5 with NA/NULL.

Once the 2nd data point is obtained, it has to be the new reference point (64.58) and the next difference has to be calculated from this 2nd point obtained as shown below.

So the output should be like this:

`65.12, NA, NA, 64.58, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,  67.28, 64.76,NA .....`

Any Ideas or Suggestions will be great help.

Comment: You can create a condition with `replace(v1, c(FALSE, abs(diff(v1)) < 0.5), NA)` `NULL` cannot exist in a vector

Comment: @akrun Nope. Not working. I need the difference to be calculated from the new point once its obtained. Yours just checks the diiference value for successive values and the result obtained is 65.12    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA 67.28 64.76    NA  , which is not what I am looking for

Comment: Not clear about the new point

Comment: Your decsription is `I want to replace the successive values which have absolute difference of less than 0.5 with NA/NULL`.  Also, not clear why it should be reset on `64.58`

Comment: (65.12-64.94) and (65.12-64.76) are < 0.5 so they are replaced with NA.(65.12-64.78) > 0.5, so we don't replace 64.58 with NA and keep it as it is.    Now this 64.58 is our reference vale and further difference is taken as given. (64.58-64.40) ,(64.58-64.76).... and so on until we get 67.28.     Now, we do (67.28-64.76) is >0.5, we keep 64.76 as it is. next step would be (64.76-64.40) , (64.76-x) and so on. Hope its clear now

Comment: This is really similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57597912/removing-data-points-having-difference-less-than-2-degrees/57598106#57598106. Using the solution with the loop you just need slight modifications to do what you want, tell me if it is ok for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there's a decent way to vectorize this, so I'm going with a straight `for` loop solution. Despite `for` loops being non-ideal in R from a speed standpoint, this seems to scale well to millions of data points.

```
a <- c(65.12, 64.94, 64.76, 64.58, 64.40, 64.58, 64.76, 64.94, 64.76, 67.28,64.76, 64.40)

cleanVect <- function(a){
    x <- a[1]

    b <- c()
    b[1] <- x

    for (i in 2:length(a)){
        if (abs((x - a[i])) < .5){
            b[i] <- NA
        } else {
            x <- a[i]
            b[i] <- a[i]
        }
    }
    return(b)
}
cleanVect(a)

 [1] 65.12    NA    NA 64.58    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA 67.28 64.76    NA
```

And this runs plenty fast for 8,000 entries; I tested up to 8 million and it still runs in about 3 seconds.

```
x1 <- round(runif(8000,55,56),2)
cleanVect(x1)

           test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1 cleanVect(x1)          100     0.3        1      0.28     0.02         NA        NA
```

Comment: Thanks for the timing verification too.