# Getting length of fractional part of a decimal

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to get length of fractional part
ex : 0.063 - 3 , 0.04 -2
i got fractional part using this

```
df['fractional_part'] = np.modf(df['mod_text'])[0]
```

I tried to get count of fractional part using this

```
df['count_fractional_part']  = df['fractional_part'].apply(lambda x:int(len(str(x).split('.')[1])))
```

But i want to do it with out apply function
Is there any way doing it with numpy

Comment: What's your goal in wanting to avoid the `apply()` function?

Comment: As your `df['mod_text']` are numbers, the result depends on the formatting you apply (or that is internally applied by default) when you print or convert the numbers to string. With standard formatting you could also simply use `(df1.mod_text % 1).astype(str).str.len()-2`, but as @Chelmy88 pointed out, this will yield unexpected (not wrong!) results for e.g. 12.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert values to strings, then use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), select second value and get length by [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'mod_text':[0.063, 0.04]})

df['count_fractional_part'] = df['mod_text'].astype(str).str.split('.').str[1].str.len()

print (df)
   mod_text  count_fractional_part
0     0.063                      3
1     0.040                      2
```

Answer (score 2):

Yo can do:

`[len(str(x).split(".")[1]) for x in df['mod_text']]`

So you don't use `np.modf` either.

Indeed wit `np.modf` you have rounding issues. If you do: `np.modf(12.2)[0]`, you get 0.1999999999999993, and thus 16 digits... While of you do `len(str(12.2).split(".")[1]` you get 1 as expected

Comment: I don't think using a `for` loop is better than `pandas.apply()` in any sense

Comment: Indeed, but the question was about not using apply.

Comment: @jezrael Is it possible that `apply` would actually be a better choice than plain `for`, because `pandas` does some sort of backstage compilation in `apply`?

Comment: @Aryerez - It depends, but if need better performance then obviously yes.

Comment: @jeztael It might, but I realized that for small loops raw loops might perform better. Indeed, built in function have a broad range of application that might add some overhead, and in the end they do a loop internally. See eg the benchmark here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57597912/removing-data-points-having-difference-less-than-2-degrees/57598106#57598106

Comment: I wanted to do it without any loop or apply function

Comment: @PadegalSaigiriraj At some point you will have to loop over all the component of the df to do the computation, throughout a direct loop or throughout apply function or similar...

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to string then split by the point(".") then get the length of position 1

```
>>> number=0.11110
>>> len(str(number).split(".")[1])
4
```